# How to stop docker container still running in circleci?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, circleci

I have a step in my pipeline in circleci that launch a docker-compose on a real machine.
Sometime this step fail and the docker container is still running after the end of the pipeline !
All the following pipeline are affected and also fail due to the docker still beeing up.

Is there a way to force the docker container to stop when the pipeline fail ?

Comment: What do you mean by "a real machine"? Is it a remote host?

Comment: Yes it's a self hosted runner, sorry for the late reply